# Confirmation email not sent upon registration BUT…

Tags: civievent, email

If a user registers for an event the registration confirmation email does not get sent. The registration completes, however they see this error message:

[image: Mailing Error]

I am using mail() and when I test Outbound Mail settings, it works.

Now the BUT… part:
If I register a participant using the Register Event Participant option in the backend, the registration completes and the registration confirmation email is sent to the user.

I am stumped.

Were running CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Wordpress 4.3.1

When I 'Redirect to database' the emails get into the spool table. See Screenshot:
[image: civicrm_mailing_spool]

Comment: You say you are using mail() in your outbound mail settings, /(as opposed to SMTP or Sendmail..), odd that the error msg references SMTP.  What happens if you set 'Redirect to database', do your reg.emails at least get into the spool table?

Comment: When I 'Redirect to database' the emails get into the spool table. I have updated the question with this info and a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks JUrsulak- I think that confirms no problem w/event reg. data or mail template. I just set up a 4.6 test system, selected 'mail()' and though the test email was sent, reg. conf. email got error - however using 'SMTP' reg. email was sent successfully. Is SMTP set up on your server (ping port 25)? can you try it?

Comment: Thanks Lesley. SMTP is set up on our server. However, we use Google for Nonprofits for our email. I'm assuming that throws a wrench into things???

I have looked at trying to setup SMTP using Gmail but none of that seemed to work.

Comment: Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.gmail.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Use Secure Connection: Yes (this can be TLS or SSL depending on your mail client)
Username: your GMail/Google account
Password: your GMail/Google password
Port: 465 or 587 - I am not sure if and whether you can set this up using your (host) CPanel. What did you do/how did you try to setup SMTP?  btw I wonder if your host allows php mail(), is that something they can tell you?

Comment: I checked the Civi PHP code - 'Save and Test Email' is not the same as code used to send confirm. emails (not surprising)..

Comment: So never mind about asking whether your host allows php mail, the 'test email' and backend reg worked

Comment: I found that mail() worked for me after I modified CRM/Utils/Mail.php, line 99... to only add 'CC' or 'BCC' if the params are not blank, that is, insert: "if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params) != NULL){ " before "$headers['Cc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params);"   Since PHP isn't a compiled language for better or worse, it is not hard to try this out.  I tried it w/event registration with and without CC

Comment: Here's the mod to Mail.php:
    if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params) != NULL){
      $headers['Cc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc', $params);
    }
    if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('bcc', $params) != NULL){
      $headers['Bcc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('bcc', $params);
    }